# How to turn on warnings as errors for ASP.NET Web Site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, web-config, compiler-warnings

Tried the following in web.config but no method works:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/nowarn:108,109,114,169,414,436,618">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="true" />
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/nowarn:108,109,114,169,414,436,618 /warnaserror+">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/nowarn:108,109,114,169,414,436,618 /warnaserror">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Note: this is for [Web Site not Web Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx), so it can not be done in the project properties as there is no project.

**Update**

This was a mistake on my part. I was looking at the warnigs on the Error List screen and assumed they are compiler warnings but they were not.

Setting only `<providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="true" />` works correctly.

Comment: tried after rebuilding the project ?

Comment: yes, otherwise they might not have been shown

Comment: Perhaps if you have time, write your discover in the form of an answer and post it, and select it as the answer.  You are allowed to answer your own questions after a period time if I recall correctly.